# Different PDF output in IE vs FF and Chrome using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using HTML tables and a little CSS for colors to output a PDF.  The PDF looks just like it's supposed to when generating the file using Firefox and Chrome but when I try in IE it is missing all its colors and all the text isn't aligned correctly: it is slanted (like each line starts with one more tab than the previous line).  I find this weird since PHP is generating the PDF on the server side.  Anyone else experience this?

Using `$aPdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, 'L');` and `$aPdf->Output('testfile.pdf', 'I');` with TCPDF Version 5.9.062.

Comment: You're right, that is weird since PHP is generating on the server. Have you tried saving the PDF to a static file locally and opening that same file in various browsers? That will take the server out of the equation and give you absolute proof that the different browsers are rendering exactly the same file differently. Plus if you can't resolve it, you might then be able to provide that PDF file to the TCPDF developers as a test case.

Comment: I've tried having the file be saved directly on the server, so it doesn't come back to the browser, and it's still messed when I open the file.  It must be that IE does some type of transformation to the data that's being posted that Chrome and FF doesn't.  The field type is hidden, I'm going to try a text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was using `<input type="hidden">` and that was causing errors when posting the html to generate the PDF.  So I changed it to `<input style="display:none" type="text" />` and IE was ok with that.  So it was an issue with the way IE handles `<input type="hidden">`